# I deleted ruby 2.1.1 cannot install it again mac os 10.7.5

Tags: ruby, macos, installation, osx-lion, reinstall

I'm a total beginner with the terminal and I wanted to learn Rails. I have a mac with Lion 10.7.5 on it. I wanted to install Rails and it seems to be installed and then when i typed rails -v i got this message :

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

So I went to stack overflow and saw lots of people having the same problem. So I tried the things people recommended and none of them worked. Then I took the not that smart decision to delete the ruby2.1.1 in order to reinstall it with :

```
 brew install ruby
```

And here start the mess :

```
Warning: You seem to have osx-gcc-installer installed.
Homebrew doesn't support osx-gcc-installer. It causes many builds to fail and
is an unlicensed distribution of really old Xcode files.
Please install the CLT or Xcode 4.6.3.
```

I already have Xcode 4.6.3

```
Warning: It appears you have MacPorts or Fink installed.
```

Not sure what to do about it

```
Software installed with other package managers causes known problems for
Homebrew. If a formula fails to build, uninstall MacPorts/Fink and try again.

Warning: ruby-2.1.1 already installed
```

So I typed in : 
    rvm use ruby 2.1.1

And I got :

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin' is   not at first place,
usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.1.1'.
ruby-2.1.1 is not installed.

To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.1.1'
```

so I did it and I got :

```
Downloaded archive checksum did not match, archive was removed!
If you wish to continue with not matching download add '--verify-downloads 2' after the command.
Downloading https://rvm.io/binaries/osx/10.7/x86_64/ruby-2.1.1.tar.bz2 failed.
```

and

```
Error running 'env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-O3 - 
I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include ./configure -- 
prefix=/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1 --disable-install-doc --enable-shared',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/me/.rvm/log/1397387601_ruby-2.1.1/configure.log
```

Thank you if you can help I don't know what to do know

Ps : Other test: 
ruby -v I got

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin11.0]
```

rvm list

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin' is  not at first place,
     usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
     it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
     to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.1.1'.
```

rvm use ruby-2.1.1

```
 ruby-2.1.1 is not installed.
```

echo $PATH

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin:/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin:/Users/me/.rvm/bin:/Users/me/.rvm/bin:/Users/me/.rvm/bin
```

which ruby

```
/usr/bin/ruby
```

rvm uninstall ruby-2.1.1

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin' is not at first place,
     usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
     it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
     to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.1.1'.
ruby-2.1.1 - #removing src/ruby-2.1.1..
ruby-2.1.1 - #removing default ruby interpreter............
```

and my .bash_profile

```
 [[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile 
  [[ -s      "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" 
# Load RVM into a shell     session *as a function* 
 PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

and finally my .bashrc

```
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Comment: put `/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin` to the first place on path. Do you use zsh or bash?

Comment: Hi when I do so it answered :

    -bash: /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin: is a directory 

So I guess I use -bash

Comment: You do something others... just add to your shell init script: `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin`, and then `source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` to the end of it.

Comment: I had "PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" and "source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" to the .bashrc file at /Users/me. Then I relaunch rvm install ruby 2.1.1 and I got the same errors.
Thanks for helping me

Comment: please move then into the `.bash_profile`

Comment: Still the same error. But I just saw I forget to report one error :
"% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 6671k  100 6671k    0     0   463k      0  0:00:14  0:00:14 --:--:--  496k
Downloaded archive checksum did not match, archive was removed!
If you wish to continue with not matching download add '--verify-downloads 2' after the command.

Downloading https://rvm.io/binaries/osx/10.7/x86_64/ruby-2.1.1.tar.bz2 failed."

Comment: update your post. pls

Comment: it seems that your ruby isn't installed properly to rvm?

Comment: please also issue `rvm list`, and `ruby -v`

Comment: I guess the problem is that sometimes he thinks that ruby 2.1.1 is still installed sometimes not.
When i do rvm list I got 
`warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.1.1'.`

Comment: Ok when I do ruby -v i got  `ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin11.0]`

Comment: update post please, and issue `echo $PATH`

Comment: where the lines `/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin` from. then issue `which ruby`

Comment: I updated, thanks again for your time, when I do echo $PATH I got 
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin:/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin:/Users/me/.rvm/bin:/Users/me/.rvm/bin:/Users/me/.rvm/bin`
I put it in the main post.

Comment: I don't know where `/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin` comes from.
When I typed in which ruby I got `/usr/bin/ruby`

Comment: it seems that `/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin` contains no ruby. because `/usr/bin` is after it. you just need properly setup the ruby 2.1.1. Just uninstall, and then install it again.

Comment: When I do rvm reinstall ruby 2.1.1 I go the same errors. Do you mean reinstall rvm ?

Comment: please issue `rvm uninstall ruby-2.1.1` and update the post with its answer

Comment: So i did, and i got 
`Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.1.1'.
ruby-2.1.1 - #removing src/ruby-2.1.1..
ruby-2.1.1 - #removing default ruby interpreter............`

Comment: ` #removing default ruby interpreter............` this is removed the ruby. please show `.ruby_profile`.

Comment: Do you know where is .ruby_profile please ?

Comment: sorry `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: ~/.bash_profile : 
`[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin
source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`

Comment: I updated it, thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in last line of your **.bash_profile**, please change it as follows, and retry:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile 
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin
```

Comment: I did replace with your text, then  when I run rvm install ruby-2.1.1 I got the exact same error as before.

Comment: Something mixups into the PATH, we need to find what is exactly. please update post with .bashrc

Comment: And that is not error, just warning. And below it valid text for the command

Comment: I just updated it with .bashrc . I don't know what you mean by provide output for /etc/profile when I typed it in the terminal I have to "sudo" it, ortherwise permission is denied `sudo: /etc/profile: command not found`

Comment: I did something stupid now I'm lost. I found an old railsinstaller uninstaller and launch it. Now I have a message `-bash: /etc/profile.d/sm.sh: No such file or directory
-bash: /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: No such file or directory`

Comment: @real1 Where have you it?

Comment: In the terminal at each opening. Maybe I should reinstall os X.

Comment: Hi, I'm currently having lots of trouble with my other softwares to, so I'm gonna reinstall the entire Mac os X. Thanks a lot for your time, I learned a lot about way things works with os X and Ruby through this exchange. Cheers!